# Dismiss CNContactPickerViewController on call button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Let's say, we have simple application with one view controller and single bar button item which will open `CNContactPieckerViewController`. So, I enter into picker view, choose contact, enter into details view. If there is implementation for `contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty:` delegate method in my view controller, pressing a call button will call delegate method and `CNContactPickerViewController` will be dismissed and for making a call I need to handle everything manually in delegate method. But if there is no implementation for `contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty:` delegate method, call will be made (based on what kind of call did you choose - GSM, WhatsApp or something else) but `CNContactPickerViewController` won't be dismissed.

**Question**

is there any possibility dismiss `CNContactPickerViewController` without losing functionalities for handling calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add observer while call connected and disconnected for both states and can dismiss the `CNContactPickerViewController` controller. but i would suggest use `contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty :` delegate to achieve this functionality.

1.import CallKit framework

`#import <CallKit/CXCallObserver.h>`

`#import <CallKit/CXCall.h>`

2.Conform class to `CXCallObserverDelegate` protocols.

3.Make strong reference to `CXCallObserver` object like as

`@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallObserver *callObserver;`

4.Initialize callObserver object while you are presenting `CNContactPieckerViewController` like as

`CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
 [callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
 _callObserver = callObserver;`

5.Finally implement the delegate method

```
-(void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.hasConnected) {
        NSLog(@"********** voice call connected **********/n");

    } else if(call.hasEnded) {
        [(your CNContactPieckerViewController object) dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"********** voice call disconnected **********/n");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Before posting here a question, I've already tried this solution, but it still not complete for me in my specific situation. Still I need to mention that this can be solution. Yes, the `contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty:` would be perfect solution, but in my case, I don't won't to overwrite default functionality for calling, so need to find way around.

Comment: so what actually you want to do,what's the exactly situation .

Comment: Ok, during my investigation, I found out that problem isn't in this solution but in strange behavior of main view controller in my app. So, based on what I have now, my opinion is that in this kind of case this is the best way around solution. Thanks for reply :)